# How to order and index the column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am thinking a way to order the data frame and create a column to sort the order.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'YYYYMM':[202206,202207,202206,202209,202206,202207]})
   YYYYMM
0  202206
1  202207
2  202206
3  202209
4  202206
5  202207
```

Then I tried to order it by using numpy

```
df['order'] = np.argsort(df['YYYYMM'])
   YYYYMM  order
0  202206      0
1  202207      2
2  202206      4
3  202209      1
4  202206      5
5  202207      3
```

However, I want the same value can share the same order like

```
   YYYYMM ORDER
0  202206 0
1  202207 1
2  202206 0
3  202209 2
4  202206 0
5  202207 1
```

What should I do to achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with `method='dense'`, convert to integers and subtract `1`:

```
df['order'] = df['YYYYMM'].rank(method='dense').astype(int).sub(1)
print (df)
   YYYYMM  order
0  202206      0
1  202207      1
2  202206      0
3  202209      2
4  202206      0
5  202207      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with the `method='dense'` parameter and subtract 1 as the first ranks is 1 and convert to integer:

```
df['order'] = df['YYYYMM'].rank(method='dense').sub(1).astype(int)
```

output:

```
   YYYYMM  order
0  202206      0
1  202207      1
2  202206      0
3  202209      2
4  202206      0
5  202207      1
```